# How would I add additional rules to the transfer in ERC20

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20

Hello everyone I want to make simple erc20 token that follows this rules

1. 2% goes to the specified wallet
2. 3% goes to the liquidity pool
3. 5% is sold and sent to the specified wallets
   I got code for the first one but I cant to make the rest I hope someone can help

```
function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
     require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
     require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
     // Rule 1 
     require(_value%100 == 0);
     uint fee = _value/100; 
     _balance[thirdPartyAddress].add(fee);
     // Rule1 END
     _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount);
     _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount + fee);
     emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
}
```

Comment: You need a fixed-point math library. I recommend using [PRBMath](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: I got safe math this function is from simple erc token just modified

Comment: SafeMath is not a fixed-point math library. And you don't need it in Solidity v0.8 anymore. Take a look at PRBMath, specifically at this [code snippet in the README](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math/tree/42f98250ba6b412abd9b13d57a9b1ea9932250dc#prbmathud60x18sol), it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SafeMoons contract [SafeMoon source](https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol). Although I dislike SafeMoon their contract does exactly what you are looking for. I use it for swapAndLiquify.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).